# Cakephp: Include php script in .ctp file

Tags: cakephp

I want to add captcha in myfile.ctp. For this i found source for captcha along with some resource files includs(js, php).
I know the folder for js files & include this file using `<?php echo $javascript->link(array('ajax_captcha.js'));?>`. But I don't know where to place .php file &
also how to include it in myfile.ctp

**Or if anybody help me to implement Captcha in Cakephp.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your js, use `$javascript->link('ajax_captcha',false);` Not the omission of the extension. false will place it in the  section of the HTML. This will look for the script in `webroot/js`

Personally, I would just use a standard php include directive for the php side of things, bearing in mind that the location will be relative to webroot, i.e. `'/myPHP/captcha.php'`will be `webroot/myPHP/captcha.php`.

Don't forget, CakePHP  *is* PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a plugin or component, http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/captcha-component-with-phpcaptcha

This works very well with PHPCaptcha for all your Human vs Computer shenanigans. Feel free to google around for your preferred plugin/component.

Answer (score 0):

There is another article in the bakery - [Integrate CakePHP with Kcaptcha](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/integrate-cakephp-with-kcaptcha) (read the comments there too). I have successfully implemented kcaptcha in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Elements are a good way to pull code that gets sprinkled over and over around various views:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements